# Extract Value from Poorly formed JSON result

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter, regexextract, json

I have a Google script that returns the following result set, but when I try to get the value for `asking_price` or `asking_price_condition` it comes back undefined. I assume it's because of some {} subsets are nested in the result.  any help.

```
{manheim_sequence=30, option_air_conditioning=true, option_rear_park_aid=false, gross_vehicle_weight=6950, year=2017, option_tilt_tele_wheel=true, intake_date_old=null, seats=Cloth, manheim_maa=5208221, option_non_factory_exhaust=false, option_power_windows=true, manheim_submitted_on=2018-11-28T15:04:57.000-05:00, transmission=Automatic, ext_paint=White, option_cd=true, option_power_door_locks=true, product_id=88423, needs_transport=false, vin=1C6RR7LM7HS874776, model=1500, id=88495, fuel_type=Diesel, option_airbags=true, arrival_date=2018-11-15, mileage=8098, option_adj_pedals=false, option_air_susp=false, option_chrome_wheels=true, option_pan_roof=false, option_wireless_cell=false, option_alum_wheels=false, option_dvd=false, drivetrain=4 Wheel Drive, option_dual_climate_control=true, engine_cylinders=6 Cylinder, option_alloy_wheels=false, option_altered_suspension=false, condition=4.3, active_admin_comments=[Ljava.lang.Object;@35547aa4, option_cruise_control=true, option_power_steering=true, manheim_auction_number=14, option_running_bd=true, style=Big Horn 4x4 Crew Cab 5'7" Box, option_premium_sound=false, option_moonroof=false, custom_description=Bought from AB , option_power_mirrors=true, option_rear_window_defroster=false, option_addl_rear_seat=false, trim_level=Big Horn, has_unibody_damage=false, option_power_seats=true, option_tinted_glass=false, has_title=null, option_child_seat_anchors=false, clean_code=TD, owner_partner={website=, bill_address_id=5168, manheim_auction_price=100, role=0, is_active=true, ship_address_id=5169, qb_edit_sequence=1550083245, sales_contact=BRIAN PIGER 717-553-3080, created_at=2016-05-19T14:41:00.000-04:00, qb_list_id=80000983-1463508945, manheim_maa=5208221, client_id=4, alt_phone=, account_id=KELL3, resale_number=5208221, updated_at=2019-02-13T13:43:46.000-05:00, phone=7175533080, partner_category=1, name=KELLER BROS DODGE, manheim_auction_highline_price=150, id=4609, fax=7176261885, email=bpiger@kellerbrosdodge.com}, option_power_brakes=true, option_rear_ac=false, option_heated_seats=null, oem_int_color=Diesel Gray/Black, option_heated_p_seat=true, make=Ram, manheim_lane_number=9, option_antilock_brakes=false, option_sat_radio=true, product={custom_option_assignments=[Ljava.lang.Object;@3a5e5ef2, notes=, system_stock_number=10050730, expense_total=10, buyer_id=51, product_category_id=4, sale_note=, external_url=, product_status_updated_by=Jimmy Harish, id=88423, estimated_value=30300, payment_received=false, total_spent=10, product_status_id=2, location_vendor_id=null, owner_partner_id=4609, sold_to_partner_id=null, as_product_type=Car, payment_reference=, created_by=Charlie Null, stock_number=10050730MS, report_value_adjustment=0, location_notes=, product_status_updated_at=2019-02-18T15:34:03.000-05:00, retail_user_id=null, purchase_price=0, updated_by=Bill Spencer, purchase_date=2019-02-18, payment_deposit_date=null, asking_price_condition=, transport_partner_id=null, created_at=2018-11-15T08:44:29.000-05:00, buyback=false, intake_date=null, gl_payment_line_id=null, product_images=[Ljava.lang.Object;@445d7c3a, purchase_fee=0, primary_image_id=null, updated_at=2019-02-21T12:29:50.000-05:00, sale_date=null, price_bid=0, location_customer_id=null, sale_reference=, gl_payment_line_payment_index=null, sale_fee=0, vendor_partner_id=null, in_arbitration=false, payment_status=0, serial_number=1C6RR7LM7HS874776, location_vendor_name=, sale_price=0, location_type=1, location_customer_name=, current_product_purchase_id=55783, asking_price=32800, record_complete=true}, general_description=BRIGHT WHITE CLEARCOAT, A/T, CLOTH, DIESEL, 4WD, V6, AIRBAG S/C, A/C, DUAL CLIMATE, PWRDL, PMIRRORS, PSEATS, PWRW, CHROME WHEELS, HTD D SEAT, HTD P SEAT, CD, SAT RADIO, RUNNING BD, 6950GVW, BOUGHT FROM AB , option_heated_d_seat=true, option_backup_cam=false, option_air_bag_side_curtain=true, option_active_susp=false, title_date=null, option_non_factory_wheels=false, option_dual_moonroof=false, option_child_seat=false, option_sun_moon_roof=false, oem_ext_color=Bright White Clearcoat, int_color=Gray, option_navigation=false, option_conv_ht=false, option_altered_intake=false}
```

Comment: do you rly need a script or could be formula too?

Comment: It's a script that runs and pulls in a number of lines, so it really needs to be part of the automated script to pull out the data and update the correct single value in a field.   I'm up for anything now, if it works. not sure if the formula would overwrite when the script runs.

Comment: it would if the script wont delete the formula. not sure how your script works but lets say it will import this json in some cell and then you could extract your desired values with formula in some another cell. or also it would be possible to ditch the script and do this just with formula... it all depends on a lot of things tat are not mentioned so not rly sure...

Comment: yes I could import this into a cell and then formula it into another cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ", ", "×"), "×")), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&"asking_price="&"*",
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ", ", "×"), "×"))))), "=(.+)")
```

[image]